# How can I know when a custom ListView is scrolling Up?

Tags: android, listview

I can detected when I scroll until the very bottom using 
`.size() - 1` of my elem. But if I start to scroll up at the middle of the list, how can I know it, in the method GetView() of course.

Comment: what you have to try?

Comment: Found how to do it... Using `setOnScrollListener` . I finally found a way to do it with this method. Thank's !

Comment: ok then post your answer or delete your question as you find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to do it which works more or less well...

```
list.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
                    private int mLastFirstVisibleItem;

                    @Override
                    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                                         int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

                        if(mLastFirstVisibleItem<firstVisibleItem) /* DOWN */
                        {
                            scrolling = false;
                        }
                        if(mLastFirstVisibleItem>firstVisibleItem) /* UP*/
                        {
                            scrolling = true;
                        }
                        mLastFirstVisibleItem=firstVisibleItem;

                    }
                });
```